# POST with Python not working

Tags: python, post, http-post, python-3.5

I've read many posts on the Internet, but none of them seems to work for me.
I have a web form which requires an username and a password in order to log in. Here's a snippet of code among those I tried so far

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'login' : 'user', 'password' : 'pwd'})
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com/login.php?%s" % params)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

However it gives me back the login page source instead of the "user panel" that appears after log in. If I write `https:/example.com/login.php?login=user&password=pwd` in the url bar of the browser, it logs me in. The goal is to get the page source that appears **after** logging in (the "user panel").
Can anyone help me please?

Using Python 3.5

Comment: Maybe the login just redirects you to the user panel after the login or maybe you are missing some headers on the request

Comment: You are making a `GET` request instead of a `POST`.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use requests, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've been trying to make it work for 20 mins on Windows, let me try on Unix

Comment: @LucaMozzo, can you share the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage is

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com/login.php", data=params)
```

From [`urllib.request` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

> *data* may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or `None` if no such data is needed.

Note that this will send a `POST` request instead of a `GET`. If you *have to* send a `GET` request, you can simply do the following:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com/login.php?user={0}&password={1}".format('user', 'pwd'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get back the login page also by doung in this way (it asks me an array of bytes so I had to write `data=params.encode("utf-8")` instead)

Comment: @LucaMozzo The site might require a `GET` request. Did you try the second method?

Comment: The HTML says "method=post", but I've just tried it and still nothing!

Comment: @LucaMozzo if you use the last line from Selcuk's answer it should be the same as if you put it in the browser url bar. Have you run that line of code?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation for urllib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#examples), you need to pass keyword argument `data` (or the second positional argument) to `urlopen`, instead of adding them to the url:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query", params)
print f.read()
```